# How can I copy all files in a sub-directory of Downloads folder into another sub-directory in var/www/?

Tags: command-line, permissions, filemanager

I downloaded Magento 2.0 into Downloads folder and extracted all the files into temp_extract.  Now I want to copy all files inside temp_extract into var/www/magento.  I cannot figure out how to do it.  I tried several copy command-lines, but none worked. Also, I tried several file managers, including Gentoo, Xfe, PCManFM, and Nemo.  None of them helped.  I have given all permissions, i.e., d rwx rwx r-x, to magento directory.  With most file managers when I copy and paste the files, they say that I do not have permissions.  With Gentoo, I ended up transferring temp_extract into magento directory, but I couldn't figure out the command-line to move from temp_extract into magento.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: is it`www/var/magento`or `/var/www/magento` & why you want to move to `/var/www/` directory?

Comment: Sorry it is var/www/magento.  Because I am installing magento in that directory, according to instructions given.

Comment: @Brian ok but that does NOT mean you copy the installation files to /var/www/ ;-)

Comment: do u have a folder `magento` in `/var/www/`?

Comment: I haven't yet figured out how to install magento.  I do have a folder magento in /var/www/.

Comment: Then u can run `sudo cp Downloads/temp_extract/* /var/www/magento/`

Comment: It says:  `cp: cannot stat '/Downlads/temp_extract/*': No such file or directory brian@brian-VirtualBox   My command prompt has been changed to  `#magento:/$ apparently by Gentoo.

Comment: @Brian As you say, you don't yet know how to install it, please give me a link to the same download you used, it is unlikely you move the files manually like that, there will be an install.sh script or a make file or something.

Comment: @MicrosoftLinux You need to add a `~/` to that path, like this `~/Downloads/temp_extract/* /var/www/magento/` or `cd` in to `temp_extract` first.

Answer (score 0):

The file mangers gives you a `permission denied` error as you are copying files in to a folder owned by `root`, `/var`,you should not change the permissions of system folder like `/var`, you have two options to move these files, first

```
sudo cp /file/you/want/to/copy /folder/you/want/to/copy/to
```

If you like to move them via a `gui` you can run a `root` `gui` like this

```
gksu nemo
```

You can swap `nemo` for the name of your favourite file manager.

To copy the specific files you requested, this is the correct syntax

```
sudo cp -R ~/Downloads/temp_extract/ /var/www/magento/
```

As you say in comments

> I haven't yet figured out how to install magento

You should provide the download you used and any tutorial you followed as it seems unlikely you would need to copy these files manually, there is possibly some kind of installation script you can run to automate the processes.

Comment: @ mark  It doesn't work.  Still I am getting the message:  `cp: cannot stat 'Downloads/temp_extract/*': No such file or directory`  The problem is I have to copy the file two directory backward to the root directory, and then three directory forward to the magento directory.  Still I haven't figured out the copy command for this.

Comment: Try the edited command

Comment: Page not found.... @Brian, please comment here to not fill up jorges notifications with our conversation.

Comment: You mean this? https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Answer (score 0):

You have to be superuser in order to copy something to `/var/www` and since you are copying a folder you need to include the `-R` parameter to the `cp` command for it to copy recursively. It would be something like this:

```
sudo cp -R ~/Downloads/temp_extract/ /var/www/magento/
```

Comment: I have been typing everything as a superuser.  I typed sudo su.  I also added sudo before every command.  Still I am getting the same `cannot stat` error message.

Comment: @Brian If you give me a download link to your package, I will install it on my pc and then give you instructions, but I have to make sure we have the same package.

Comment: @mark  Here is the download link to Magento CE 2.0: [https://www.magentocommerce.com/download]  Thanks.

Comment: @mark  I have already spent four days trying to install magento; it may end up taking a lot of your time.  I will post the question on Magento's company blog or on StackExchange Magento.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just copy all of the files from one dir to the other recursively, you can use something like this:

```
cp -r /home/user1/dir1/* /var/www/dir2/
```

If you wanted to copy the entire directory recursively, it would look more like this:

```
cp -r /home/user1/dir1 /var/www
```